# Using Power BI Is it Possible To Decode a URL?

Tags: powerbi

is there a function to take a url or part of a url and convert it in to human reable please ?

ie

%7b%22pageSize%22:500,%22previousIds%22:%5b3%5d,%22nextIds%22:%5b593%5d%7d&search=%7b%22filter%22:%5b%7b%22op%22:%22gte%22,%22field%22:%22id%22,%22value%22:%220%22%7d%5d%7d

to

{"pageSize":500,"previousIds":[3],"nextIds":[593]}&search={"filter":[{"op":"gte","field":"id","value":"0"}]}

?

Tried a few approaches but does not come through well.

Thanks

EDIT:
My Approach which errors

```
// Custom function to decode a URL-encoded string
DecodeUrlEncodedString = (url as text) =>
    let
        // Replace URL-encoded characters
        decodedString = Text.Replace(url, "%7b", "{", Replacer.ReplaceText),
        decodedString1 = Text.Replace(decodedString, "%22", """", Replacer.ReplaceText),
        decodedString2 = Text.Replace(decodedString1, "%3a", ":", Replacer.ReplaceText),
        decodedString3 = Text.Replace(decodedString2, "%2c", ",", Replacer.ReplaceText),
        decodedString4 = Text.Replace(decodedString3, "%5b", "[", Replacer.ReplaceText),
        decodedString5 = Text.Replace(decodedString4, "%5d", "]", Replacer.ReplaceText),
        decodedString6 = Text.Replace(decodedString5, "%7d", "}", Replacer.ReplaceText)
    in
        decodedString6,
```

Failing alterntive

```
= (data as text) as text =>
let 
    DecodedText = Uri.Parts("https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next?paging=" & data)[Query][paging]
in
    DecodedText
```

Updated but failing due to Expression.Error: The field 'paging' of the record wasn't found.

```
converturl = (uri as text) as text => 
let
    textBeforePaging = Text.BeforeDelimiter(uri, "?paging"),
    textAfterPaging = Text.BetweenDelimiters(uri, "paging=", " "),
    out = Uri.Parts(textBeforePaging & Text.Replace(textAfterPaging , "&", "%26"))[Query][paging]
in
    out,
```

Comment: *Tried a few approaches* - please (re)read [ask] and make sure you have a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WUjVPUjUyKkhMTw3OrEoFMq1MDQx0QEJFqWWZ+aXFninFIFFV0yRjVdMUkExeakUJQtTUEiSuap4SU2pgYGRWnJpYlJxhCzE2LTOnJLUIqhAilF8A5hoZpZeAbNMBq0rNSYGKZqZABcsSc0pToYIGQAy0AGKNUmwsAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Encoded = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Decoded", each Uri.Parts("http://contoso?a=" & Text.Replace([Encoded], "&", "%26"))[Query][a])
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

See example 2 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerquery-m/uri-parts

And as a function:

```
(data as text) as text => 
let
    out = Uri.Parts("http://contoso?a=" & Text.Replace(data, "&", "%26"))[Query][a]
in
    out
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added my version so far. I need to use it in the code as I need to convert for use in a header hence pulling the url and making it a human readable to prevent fails. I do not want to move to a table. Thanks T

Comment: Updated answer with function form. Note than I am encoding `&` first. In your example, why is `&` not encoded?

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted for the benefit of all.

Comment: This solution works for the first feild but not all of the url.

Comment: Provide an example of it not working.

Comment: I've added the code above under failing alterntive. URL going in is "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next?paging=%7b%22pageSize%22%3a500%2c%22previousIds%22%3a%5b3%5d%2c%22nextIds%22%3a%5b593%5d%7d&search=%7b%22filter%22%3a%5b%7b%22op%22%3a%22gte%22%2c%22field%22%3a%22id%22%2c%22value%22%3a%220%22%7d%5d%7d". I want to get {"pageSize":500,"previousIds":[3],"nextIds":[593]}&search={"filter":[{"op":"gte","field":"id","value":"0"}]} but actually get {"pageSize":500,"previousIds":[3],"nextIds":[593]}

Comment: I am after all of it as I will need to use to it to call a URL. Thanks T

Comment: Use the function exactly as it is above in this answer. Then simply pass the string you want to decode.

Comment: Ok - that works but I'm slightly confused as to why - with http://contoso?a= and [a]... I thought these had to be specfic ?

Comment: It's a hack of a solution since PowerQuery doesn't have a native decodeUrl function. We are passing the desired string as `?a={desiredString}` to fake url, then asking it to return the same querypart `a`.

Comment: Thanks Sam - explains a lot... on to the next problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, add column ... custom column with

```
= Uri.Parts("http:/xxx?a=" & [ColumnNameHere])[Query][a]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this does work in part by getting the first feild and not all of the URL

Comment: Provide an example of it not working, as Sam said. Just saying something does not work is not helpful for debugging